# Ubuntu SDK. error: "Kit autocreation for error is not supported"

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I am using ubuntu sdk, and I am trying to create Kit for my device. I'm opening the tab "Devices" and clicking "Autocreate", and I'm getting an error: "Kit autocreation for error is not supported". Do you have an idea why could that happen?

[image]

Comment: I have a very similar one, instead of error mine says unknown. I want to create a kit for my Nexus 4 running the latest dev build.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this problem and for me cleaning up the QtCreator's local config solved the problem:

> $ rm ~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator -r

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, I thought you meant fixing the xml. :) But removing the config files there works like a charm!

Comment: Ohh, I am positive that there is a way to fix the xml file. But why bother :) Generally cleaning up QtC .config and .cache .local stuff can solve lots of odd problems.